# Move Console.WriteLine() after receiving message(Sockets)

Tags: c#, console-application

I have created a console chat application using sockets.
On both the server and client I use `Console.WriteLine("Enter message:")`. Now when I receive a message from the client or server in my console it displays:

```
"Enter message:
 Received message"
```

How can I move the `Console.WriteLine("Enter Message");` automatically to beneath all received messages?

My current server code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a username:");
        var sname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        ClientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 9000));

        Console.WriteLine("Connection has been established...");

        var RecieveThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RecieveMessage));
        RecieveThread.Start(ClientSocket);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Type message:");
            var message = Console.ReadLine();
            var custmessage = new CustomMessage() { From = sname, Message = message, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now };

            Serialize serialize = new Serialize();

            ClientSocket.Send(serialize.Serializer(custmessage));
        }
    }

    static void RecieveMessage(object socketobject)
    {
        Serialize deserialize = new Serialize();
        var client = (Socket)socketobject;

        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            var newmessage = new CustomMessage();
            client.Receive(buffer);
            object desbuffer = deserialize.Deserializer(buffer);
            newmessage = (CustomMessage)desbuffer;

            Console.WriteLine(newmessage.ToString());
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Console.CursorTop` to move to the last line on the screen, output your "Enter message", and then go back.

Here is a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop.aspx), showing how to output text at any point in the console.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, he can just use Skype and get the whole package out of the box. Console applications have there use too.